# How to convert image captured by camera using 'react-camera-pro' to a byte array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, camera

I am capturing an image using camera via 'react-camera-pro' and want to convert the captured image in a byte array, how do I do the same?
My code is like this:

```
  const camera = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

 <Camera ref={camera} facingMode='environment' aspectRatio={1 / 1}/>
 <img src={image} alt='Taken photo'/>
 <Button type='secondary' onClick={() => setImage(camera.current.takePhoto())}>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code, the `camera` ref method [`takePhoto()`](https://github.com/purple-technology/react-camera-pro/blob/d3121038c0b9345deaf0a09048f1c5e69f850ab2/src/components/Camera/Camera.tsx#L44) [returns](https://github.com/purple-technology/react-camera-pro/blob/d3121038c0b9345deaf0a09048f1c5e69f850ab2/src/components/Camera/Camera.tsx#L80-L81) the result of invoking the underlying canvas's method [`toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), which should be a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) in base64 encoding, so you can convert it to a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) using the following technique. Here's a complete example:

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQIYgKZVQGjjATzAxXS1QBUiSBfOAMyghDgCIoNUBjGAWi7LZeYJqwDcAKFCRYifNTgAlTjwCiAGwyYAdjDwBXAM4YAslogHjy+pYwBlGKhi0GTFuxUxxEifX3aeYAhtOABzDBgAIVRjADYAFgcoADE3AFUodQAKABMnVAz1AC44QxgoYG1QgEoSsoqqxAk4OC5gsrgRDHpgAA84AF42ACMYjAScbxa27Q7DdWAuDABJbRyMfqG8x0KAOkr13oB5eiyunt7qyRbgejgs+cWVtY3BgaHeAEZq-AALJgA7nBtBggaooEwoFlWKpesQeBgcnBRnF4nBtqg4GlFAAZVhXZpwDgwfRQEIYvaPJYPBZLVaHOAAak6HAuu00VRgvwJNB8AHo+XBfjAYGBDEUBettBB2ag1nyyjkAAIABl2nwAHAAmXYqvkYAIQHKVUJ8lHjeK7GCGAD8hggpKWAGIcZ8AMwAdl8-kCwXRGDa6yy5oSSTq5RNtSxlRgGoAghDUAQmtN2vBhpUkibBnAAQcIADdk4IMNg2NQ+UCanZvBDMAAF4kIYZ7RZqrsg2hLnXVpp5EEZyGHMgoFpGPxxMEB4NjBVhjQe6aeDAHMqsRwFcAHlKM-XwEZjJ+CEJLWGA4whgA2sAALo5ltt0K7Li-VBQZBGjBxmBZYBz3ktMSpIhGeg6SLy3oBDAQQhB+4DBAaP5Rso3AwBoWiISmvY1q0giYkMRgYNYm5oJg2BUMQAB8WTaPo6jqHOMwdNeICoOEeDGDAyyseEd4EcYDhOBg0L4pIhICnAFC-CQMwAG5YM4SKgSQb7YAQRSEkx6bngmak5oRZggBAWQnvcPwDJRG48SQNr+oGwnhFE5aJOUqTMIUv7WdUPwlCO0a6BOalZNUOCmSxbEYDeoUtASml9gIYAkhwAAKvwQDAEA5sFgyWQIZGoM+pIcLocAAGSlaUETcRFWR5eQhUQohVqoAA1hgqXpcZ3liYBETAfcpmbsasmUaZLQkXhY0tES3QDAgdXYAB03LTE8IwIoThBHNnxLctLRYJCZiGIYEWGHNCA0Lte30NwJomJ+AysAasnAEw2g6F4U18qNe1wJuoChKUUBcHNoARXQqDqDAj0UK1BqdGlGWsHA31TZuwz6CKfrBMgtItXNCVJe1iMQDQlFoIlpIkGAJObmamMZdoP3TXTw3MzyEhAA)

```jsx
import { Camera } from "react-camera-pro";
import { useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

function getBase64StrFromUrl(dataUrl) {
  const prefix = "base64,";
  const sliceIndex = dataUrl.indexOf(prefix);
  if (sliceIndex === -1) throw new Error("Expected base64 data URL");
  return dataUrl.slice(sliceIndex + prefix.length);
}

// https://deno.land/std@0.182.0/encoding/base64.ts?source#L137
function decode(base64Str) {
  const binString = window.atob(base64Str);
  const size = binString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(size);
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}

function Component() {
  const camera = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  // The converted byte array:
  const byteArray = useMemo(
    () => image ? decode(getBase64StrFromUrl(image)) : new Uint8Array(),
    [image],
  );

  const capturePhoto = () => camera.current && setImage(camera.current.takePhoto());

  return (
    <div>
      <Camera
        ref={camera}
        aspectRatio={1}
        errorMessages={{}}
        facingMode="environment"
      />
      <img src={image} alt="Taken photo" />
      <button onClick={capturePhoto}>Capture photo</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```